# Problemas para Mostrar ListView en Pantalla Json Retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, json, retrofit, jsonobject

Tengo la siguiente información Json y quiero sacarla por un Listview:

```
{"result":[[[12,"01",1,"Fallo de corriente",0,1],[12,"01",2,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo 
(activaci\u00F3n)",0,0],[12,"01",3,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo 
(desactivaci\u00F3n)",0,1]]]}
```

El caso es que me da un error la aplicación y no le saco punta, la tengo montada así:

La clase POST que es el pojo la tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
package com.example.lista.Interface;

import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Integer;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Post {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<List<List<Integer>>> result = null;

public List<List<List<Integer>>> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<List<List<Integer>>> result) {
    this.result = result;
}

}
```

La interfaz PostService:

```
package com.example.lista.Interface;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET; 
import retrofit2.http.Header;

public interface PostService {

String API_ROUTE = " obtenerListaAlarmasSMS";

@GET(API_ROUTE)
Call<Post> getPost(@Header("Authorization") String credencialesEnBase64);

}
```

Y el Main lo tengo de la siguiente manera

```
package com.example.lista.Interface;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.lista.R; 

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.String;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import static retrofit2.Response.error;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView list;
List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> titles  = new 
ArrayList<List<List<List<Integer>>>>();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
String usuario = new String("");
String clave = new String("");
String error = new String("Algo ha fallado");

String credenciales =  usuario + ":" + clave ;;
String credencialesEnBase64 = "Basic " + 
Base64.encodeToString(credenciales.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
    list = findViewById(R.id.list);

    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    getPosts();
}

private void getPosts() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()              
          .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.249:9096/datasnap/rest/TMetodosREST/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    PostService postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
    Call<Post> call = postService.getPost(credencialesEnBase64);


    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

                for (Post post : response.body()) {
                   titles.add(post.getResult());
               }

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
 }
 }
```

El problema viene en el for del OnResponse que me dice:

> error: for-each not applicable to expression type
>   required: array or java.lang.Iterable
>   found:    Post

No se si es por el formato del pojo que me crea o que le ocurre.

Lo que quiero es sacar la información en el `ListView`